# Issue with centre alignment of text in flexbox and headings

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Currently the text headings which are inside a flexbox (the three divs) are not aligning with the main headings on the rest of the page.
[See Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBU6x.png)

The issue appears to only take place with the character length of the text headings inside the flexbox of three divs are not the same.

[See Image of Alignment when character length is the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5nRQ.png)

I've unsuccessfully tried css alignments, but they do not appear to have an effect. My desired outcome for the three divs is something like this:

[See successful reference alignment example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJSNx.png)

The code is here:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  max-width: 100vw;
  list-style: none;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;

}
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: white;
  font-family: Poppins;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

a {
  color: black;
}

/* ----------------------------------------------------------Landing Page -------------------------------------*/
.full-height-grow {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 80vw;
  min-width: 75vw;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}




.about-container {
  padding-top: 100px;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 90vw;
  max-width: 90vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  
}

.about-img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: calc(80px + 40%);
    width: auto;
}
.about-h1 {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    color: rgb(255, 42, 95);
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-right: -30px;
    margin-left: -30px;
    font-size:calc(12px + 0.8vw) ;
}

.about-h2 {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    color: rgb(17, 17, 17);
    margin-right: -30px;
    margin-left: -30px;
    font-size:calc(15px + 2vw) ;
    font-weight: 500;
    opacity: 0.9;
}

.about-desc {
    font-family: Lora;
    font-size:calc(10px + 1.2vw);
    line-height: 1.8;
    color: #888888;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 25vw;
    margin-right: 25vw;
   overflow:hidden;
   z-index: 2;
   width: auto;
   
}
.about-tasks-container {
    align-self: center;
   background-color: blanchedalmond;
    max-width: 80vw;
    width: 80vw;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    text-align: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-grow: 1;
    
}

.about-task-heading {
 
    font-size: 80px;

}

.about-tasks-resources {

  


}

.about-tasks-learning {

   


}
```

```html
<section class="about-section">
        <div class="about-container" id="about">
            <h2 class="about-h1"> ABOUT</h2>
            <h3 class="about-h2">More About Me</h3>
            <div class="about-tasks-container">
                <div class="about-tasks-tutorials">
                    <h1 class="about-task-heading">Example</h1>
                </div>

                <div class="about-tasks-resources" >
                    <h1 class="about-task-heading">Exampler</h1>
                </div>
                
                <div class="about-tasks-learning">
                    <h1 class="about-task-heading">Examplers</h1>
                    
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        </div>
    </section>
```

(JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/2cL5h4m6/9/)

Answer (score -1):

## Try this code

Idk if this is what you wanted but you can try it and you can see if it was the thing you looked for

````css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  max-width: 100vw;
  list-style: none;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;

}
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: white;
  font-family: Poppins;
  min-height: 100vh;
}


a {
  color: black;
}

/* ----------------------------------------------------------Landing Page -------------------------------------*/
.full-height-grow {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 80vw;
  min-width: 75vw;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}




.about-container {
  padding-top: 100px;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 90vw;
  max-width: 90vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  
}

.about-img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: calc(80px + 40%);
    width: auto;
}
.about-h1 {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    color: rgb(255, 42, 95);
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-right: -30px;
    margin-left: -30px;
    font-size:calc(12px + 0.8vw) ;
}

.about-h2 {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    color: rgb(17, 17, 17);
    margin-right: -30px;
    margin-left: -30px;
    font-size:calc(15px + 2vw) ;
    font-weight: 500;
    opacity: 0.9;
}

.about-desc {
    font-family: Lora;
    font-size:calc(10px + 1.2vw);
    line-height: 1.8;
    color: #888888;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 25vw;
    margin-right: 25vw;
   overflow:hidden;
   z-index: 2;
   width: auto;
   
}
.about-tasks-container {
    align-self: center;
   background-color: blanchedalmond;
    max-width: 100vw;
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    text-align: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-grow: 0;
    
}

.about-task-heading {
 font-size: 30px;
    

}

.about-tasks-resources {

  


}

.about-tasks-learning {

   


}```
````

Comment: Unfortunately the issue with the text being misaligned still takes place